# Flask route /predict returns name error on return object

Tags: heroku, flask

Currently my Flask app works on my local machine and loads the main page to heroku just fine. However when I call my route /predict it returns a (NameError: name 'diagnosis' is not defined.)

In the /predict route I tried returning the diagnosis twice, not something I would normally try.

I do understand the h12 is a timeout error, but I believe that occurs because the route never responds within the 30 second time limit.

app link
https://lesionlegion1.herokuapp.com/

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    # data = {"success": False}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request)

        if request.files.get('file'):
            # read the file
            file = request.files['file']

            # read the filename
            # filename = file.filename

            # create a path to the uploads folder
            # filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            filepath = os.path.join(
                basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(file.filename))

            # Save the file to the uploads folder
            file.save(filepath)

           # Load the saved image using Keras and resize it to the Xception
            # format of 299x299 pixels
            image_size = (75, 100)
            im = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(filepath,
                                                    target_size=image_size,
                                                    grayscale=False)

            # preprocess the image and prepare it for classification
            image = prepare_image(im)

            global graph
            with graph.as_default():

                labels = ['Melanocytic nevi', 'Melanoma', 'Benign keratosis-like lesions', 'Basal cell carcinoma',
                          'Actinic keratoses', 'Vascular lesions', 'Dermatofibroma']

                labels = tuple(labels)

                global preds
                preds = model.predict(image)

                # convert preds array to list
                preds = preds.tolist()

                # convert list of lists to one list for rounding to work
                flat_preds = [item for sublist in preds for item in sublist]

                updated_preds = list(
                    map(lambda x: (round(x*100, 3)), flat_preds))

                dictionary = dict(zip(labels, updated_preds))

                # create a function which returns the value of a dictionary

                def keyfunction(k):
                    return dictionary[k]

            global diagnosis
            diagnosis = []

            # sort by dictionary by the values and print top 3 {key, value} pairs
            for key in sorted(dictionary, key=keyfunction, reverse=True)[:3]:

                if dictionary[key] > 0:
                    diagnosis.append([key, str(dictionary[key]) + "%"])

            return jsonify(diagnosis)
    return jsonify(diagnosis)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002, debug=True, threaded=False)
```

heroku logs

```
2019-03-27T16:47:43.394981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/predi
ct" host=lesionlegion1.herokuapp.com request_id=6a8b52fa-33c4-4c23-881f-25a626bc
73ae fwd="96.35.158.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=455 p
rotocol=https
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392702+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-27 16:47:43,390] ERROR in
app: Exception on /predict [GET]
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392716+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392719+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392721+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_reque
st()
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392723+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392725+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392726+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392728+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392729+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392732+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392734+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392735+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392736+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392738+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.end
point](**req.view_args)
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 133, in up
load
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392741+00:00 app[web.1]: return jsonify(diagnosis)
2019-03-27T16:47:43.392746+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'diagnosis' is not
defined
2019-03-27T16:47:43.393556+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.185.233 - - [27/Mar/2019:16:4
7:43 +0000] "GET /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://lesionlegion1.herokuapp.com
/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gec
ko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
2019-03-27T16:47:43.396781+00:00 app[web.1]: <Request 'https://lesionlegion1.her
okuapp.com/predict' [POST]>
2019-03-27T16:48:13.443130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
 timeout" method=POST path="/predict" host=lesionlegion1.herokuapp.com request_i
d=4ad7f81f-27a9-4b46-9423-24ccb3b59d25 fwd="96.35.158.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms
service=30052ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-03-27T16:48:14.067005+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-27 16:48:14 +0000] [4] [CR
ITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:101)
2019-03-27T16:48:15.091482+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-27 16:48:15 +0000] [109] [
INFO] Booting worker with pid: 109
```

Comment: Hi @SpacePatroller did my answer make sense and help you out?

Comment: Hello @Nathan Wright, it made sense but was not the solution to the issue. A teammate of mine was able to figure it out just this morning. It ended up being in my JS code where I had a setTimeout wrapped around the on click function to call the /predict route. On my local computer I needed it because the route need time to process but for some reason when deployed it was causing it to not run. However your response was helpful in my learning experience, so Thank You!

Comment: @NathanWright Never mind you were correct!, I was confused this morning my apologies. We also turned Async in our AJAX request to false as that was being problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `/predict` route supports both `GET` and `POST` requests but when you hit your `/predict` route from a `GET` request you're returning the value of the diagnosis variable: `return jsonify(diagnosis)` but **this `diagnosis` variable isn't defined within this scope** rather it's **defined as a global within your `POST` route** so this is why you get the following error:

> NameError: name 'diagnosis' is not defined

You can see this is caused from your `GET` method from this part of your stack trace:

> 2019-03-27T16:47:43.394981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/predi
>   ct" host=lesionlegion1.herokuapp.com request_id=6a8b52fa-33c4-4c23-881f-25a626bc
>   73ae fwd="96.35.158.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=455 p
>   rotocol=https
>   2019-03-27T16:47:43.392702+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-27 16:47:43,390] ERROR in
>   app: Exception on /predict [GET]

So in order to fix this error you need to **declare your `diagnosis` variable prior to handling a specific request type**, something along the lines of:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    diagnosis = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # ... handle POST request 
       return jsonify(diagnosis)

    # Default response for GET requests
    return jsonify(diagnosis)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002, debug=True, threaded=False)
```

Hopefully that helps!